# Execution failed for transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. (Volley)

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley, entity-relationship

I am trying to build my app on android studio virtual simulator, I have successfully tested on api level 21 and above now I am testing lower level api 19, but whenever I run i will get this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/Request$Priority.class

This is my gradle file:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.2.1'
compile 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:1.2.2'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.0.3'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'com.hedgehog.ratingbar:app:1.1.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have found many solution online regarding this but not specifically to this issue, I believe the problem is with volley, but I cannot remove any library due to my code. How should I solve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 2 different versions of volley libraries

```
 compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
 compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

use any one of the above

and I dont know about

```
compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'
```

If that is similar library to above two ,the error will still remain

Comment: Is it possible to leave both libraries? Since I am using both of them in my project.

Comment: both of them are same library why do you want both?

Comment: what is unique in these library that you may need? @JerryKo